# Memory leaking and embedded linux

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, tcp, valgrind, embedded-linux

I am running my own c++ program in embedded linux. At first VSZ is ~6000kB (top) but after 1h VSZ is increased ~100kB. In the program there is two threads. Both threads take tcp and ssl connections almost all the time.
I have run same program in depian linux with valgrind. Valgrind didn't find any errors. I didn't find a way how to compile valgrind to that embedded linux.
Is it possible that valgrind doesn't find all the error from threads? Can you help me somehow?

Comment: How did you conclude that this increase in memory usage is an error, and not correctly-implemented memory allocation?

Comment: A program that does `while(1) vector.push_back(1); ` will pretty soon run out of memory, but isn't a memory leak in a strict sense of leaking.

Comment: But in the edn of program those should be freed. My program should run forever, but when I test it with valgrind I it will exist. I have undestood that valgrind should find similar non-freed memories in the end of program. I have reviewed my code many times, and it use new operand only in startup time. If some pointer is null (over-written?) it re-allocate it, but then also error is printed and I haven't seen any errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should not jump into the conclusion that your program is "leaking memory" just because the VSZ increased after a while. This is normal especially that the program is accepting network connections. I recoomend this:

1 - If you are using busybox's "top", install procps and use its "top". It gives better info regarding memory status.

2 - Monitor the stack used by each thread. The satck can grow over time and will reflect in the VSZ.